# Is redux-thunk obsolete with useDispatch?

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

With **useDispatch** I get access to **dispatch** method. I can implement async function inside **useEffect** hooks and then call **dispatch** when I need. This pattern is described [here](https://medium.com/@rajeshnaroth/managing-async-state-with-hooks-and-redux-8ab675ae6bdf).

Does it mean that (in project with only functional components) redux-thunk is obsolete now?

Comment: Not “obsolete”, but certainly less necessary.

Comment: Thanks! So in the imaginary project that I have described there no reasons to use it?